# Query about the proof why non-orthogonal states cannot be reliably distinguished

Tags: quantum-information, measurements, hilbert-space

I have a query regarding the proof given in the book by Nielsen and Chuang on why two non-orthogonal states cannot be perfectly distinguished. The proof is given on page 87 of the 10th edition; here is the [google books link](https://books.google.de/books?id=-s4DEy7o-a0C&lpg=PP1&dq=nielsen%20and%20chuang&pg=PA87#v=onepage&q=nielsen%20and%20chuang&f=false) and below you can also find (just) the proof in the attached image.

[image: Non-orthogonality]

My main query is about the assertion $\sqrt{E_2} | \psi_1\rangle = 0$ that they make two lines below equation 2.99. What is the justification behind this?

In fact, if $\langle \psi_1 | E_2 | \psi_1\rangle = 0$, would it **not be more general** to say that $E_2 | \psi_1\rangle = |\psi_1^{\perp}\rangle$ where $|\psi_1^{\perp}\rangle$ is orthonormal to $|\psi_1\rangle$ ?

(Note: In the proof, they use $|\varphi\rangle$ to denote the orthonormal vector).

Comment: $E_2|\psi_1\rangle$ is the zero vector, which is orthogonal to any other vector.

Comment: What they do is to write $E_2$ as $\sqrt{E_2}\sqrt{E_2}$. Then, it says $(\langle\psi_1\rvert\sqrt{E_2})(\sqrt{E_2}\lvert\psi_1\rangle)=0$, which is equivalent to $\sqrt{E_2}\lvert\psi_1\rangle=0$.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch And this works only because $E_1$ and $E_2$ have a spectral decomposition because otherwise the $\sqrt{ }$ operation cannot be defined, right?

Comment: @Phoenix87 : I am not so sure if $\sqrt{E_2} |\psi_1 \rangle = 0$ also necessarily implies $E_2 |\psi_1 \rangle = 0$.

Comment: $\sqrt{E_2} \sqrt{E_2}|\psi_1\rangle = E_2|\psi_1\rangle$. $\sqrt{E_2}$ is well defined because $E_2$ is a positive operator and all its eigenvalues are contained in the non-negative real line.

Comment: Let $A$ be a positive operator s.t. $\sqrt{A} |\psi \rangle = 0$. If the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_0$ and $\lambda_1$ and $|\psi \rangle = \alpha |0 \rangle + \beta |1 \rangle$ for arbitrary $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then the equation $\sqrt{\lambda_0} \alpha + \sqrt{\lambda_1} \beta = 0$ need not imply $\lambda_0 \alpha + \lambda_1 \beta = 0$, right?

Comment: @Phoenix87: Consider the following analogy. Let $v$ be a vector lying along the $x$-axis. Then $v\cdot v\ne0$ because $v$ is auto-parallel. Suppose $R$ is a rotation about the $z$-axis of $\pi/2$ radians. Then $Rv\bot v$, i.e. $v\cdot Rv=0$. But given $v\cdot Rv=0$, we know that $Rv\ne 0$ for a general $R$ because I just showed there exists *at least one* $R$ for which that is false. Does this not generalize to Hilbert spaces?

Comment: Let $A$ be a linear operator and $v$ the zero vector, then $Av=0$.

Comment: @0celo7 Rotations aren't positive operators.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: Whoops. I think I just gave a proof that they aren't positive, didn't I?

Answer (score 3):

Like Norbert Schuch said, $E_{i}=\sqrt{E_{i}}\cdot\sqrt{E_{i}}$.The existence of $\sqrt{E_{i}}$ is guaranteed by the fact that $E_{i}$ is Hermitian and $\langle E_{i}\Psi,\Psi\rangle$ is nonnegative ($\langle E_{i}\Psi,\Psi\rangle$ describes a probability so it is greater or equal to $0$) thus $E$ is positive (by definition) so $\sqrt{E_{i}}$ exists.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! The equations become much more readable with [mathjax](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5610/75633). It'd be great if you could use it in your next posts.